# MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape sequence

Tags: java, gson

I have a json string as below:

```
{"person":[{"initials":"C. P.","familyName":"Mangum"}],"title":"Blood and tissue oxygen carriers","text":"(ed). \992d. Springer-Verlag, Heidelberg"}
```

When de-serializing above json string using gson as below:

```
gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class)
```

I see `MalformedJsonException` exception.

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape sequence at line 1 column 115 path $.test
```

Then I tried setting `JsonReader` setLenient to true

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(row));
reader.setLenient(true);
gson.fromJson(reader, MyObject.class);
```

But now I get `ClassCastException` now:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class MyObject cannot be cast to class com.google.gson.JsonElement (MyObject and com.google.gson.JsonElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Later I tried using setLenient() in GsonBuilder, but it failed with original `MalformedJsonException` exception

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
gson.fromJson(row, MyObject.class);
```

I am not sure if I can use `theString = theString.replace("\\", "\\\\");` is safe. Is there good practice to be followed?

Can I please know how I can process escaped characters as above?

Comment: It is telling the bad escape sequence occurs at pos 150. Your posted JSON is definitely shorter and valid syntactically. Please post the real JSON string, not this one.

Comment: Additionally, did you try simply put your JSON in a JSON linter (online tools, your fav IDE, jq) so that it could inspect it at tell why it goes wrong at 1:150? It's definitely quicker than making a post here.

Comment: @fluffy: I have updated original json string and it fails because of `\9` when validated with jsonlint. Please let me know how I can handle the same? I tried using setLenient() from gsonbuilder (see updates in the question) as well.

Comment: Tokens surgery like that is definitely unsafe and may be ambiguous. Can you ask your JSON provider to fix the illegal JSON it generates. I don't see a real reason trying to find a hackish workaround for an illegal thing. Note that Gson is not the only tool rejecting it. Ask your provider for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your "text" element as below , then it will be a valid json.

```
{
    "person": [{
        "initials": "C. P.",
        "familyName": "Mangum"
    }],
    "title": "Blood and tissue oxygen carriers",
    "text": "(ed). \\992d. Springer-Verlag, Heidelberg"
}
```

**Apache Commons**

If you're already using Apache commons, it provides a static method for this:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson("some string")
```

It converts any string into one that's properly escaped for inclusion in JSON.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: Can you provide an example Apache Commons dealing with the OP's original JSON?

Answer (score 1):

json is malformed, it should have a double \ for `\\992d` in the original form:

```json
{
    "person": [{
        "initials": "C. P.",
        "familyName": "Mangum"
    }],
    "title": "Blood and tissue oxygen carriers",
    "text": "(ed). \\992d. Springer-Verlag, Heidelberg"
}
```